# Setting Preferred authentication mode in Paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I try to ssh into a server and get this output:

```
$ ssh test@192.168.1.10
  Connection closed by 192.168.1.10
```

As is evident, it is immediately closing the connection as soon as the ssh connection is made.
I overcame this by doing the following:

```
  ssh -o PreferredAuthentications=keyboard-interactive test@192.168.1.10
  Password:
  Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive,hostbased).
```

My question is how do I set this in `Paramiko` python module for ssh? I have gone through the docs and didn't see any solution.

Comment: Are you asking how to input a password when using Paramiko?

Comment: No..i know how to input passwords..connect to devices..run commands etc using paramiko..I just want to know as to how to set the preferred authentication mode as keyboard interactive while I log in to a device...

Comment: But why would you want to? Paramiko will cycle through all keys etc. If you can automatically authenticate why do you want to force a manual authentication?

Comment: the reason for this is what I have mentioned in the question..some of the servers I manage close the connection abruptly if I do not mention the preferred authentication mode..when i try to login to the servers via putty,this behavior is not exhibited as putty's preferred authentication mode is keyboard interactive..how do i specify this in paramiko ?